# Problem with Nvidia graphics driver in Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 17.04

I recently updated from Ubuntu 16.10 to 17.04, and the graphic card is not working properly. It is showing this message as shown in the screenshot: [image: screenshot] instead of the login screen.

I uninstalled the Nvidia graphics driver using tty1 but still the error persists.

I am unable to login to my Ubuntu desktop.

What should I do?

Comment: Reinstall the Nvidia drivers -or- use `nomodeset` to boot THEN install the recommended drivers version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it more or less as MichelBay suggested.

I followed the instructions given at [Graphics issues after/while installing Ubuntu 16.04/16.10 with NVIDIA graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760934/graphics-issues-after-while-installing-ubuntu-16-04-16-10-with-nvidia-graphics).

1. Reboot into `GRUB`.
2. Highlight the `Ubuntu` option and press `E`.
3. Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the line beginning with `linux`.
4. Press `F10` to boot.

This allowed me to boot into the graphical environment (but not using the nvidia driver).

5. `sudo apt purge nvidia-*`.
6. Search for "Additional Drivers" in Dash.
7. Install recommended Nvidia driver via Additional Drivers tab in Software & Updates.
8. Reboot